# Could not resolve co.touchlab:kermit

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I've been working on a Kotlin Multiplatform library for a while now and I started using [kermit](https://github.com/touchlab/Kermit) logger for it. Everything builds well the only concern I have are the following warnings I am getting

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve co.touchlab:kermit:1.0.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: AddressLibrary

Unable to resolve dependency for ':@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve co.touchlab:kermit:1.0.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: AddressLibrary

Unable to resolve dependency for ':@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve co.touchlab:kermit:1.0.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: AddressLibrary
```

How can I make these go away?

Comment: Hello, Rahul! Could you please update the question if you were able to find a solution or a workaround for it?

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev I actually ended up removing the dependency since I never found the answer

Comment: Are you in the kotlinlang Slack workspace? I've found a similar question with an answer about https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49835 being related. As I don't have actual experience with the `kermit` library, I would like to ask you if it seems to be related, and if workarounds from this ticket look appropriate for your case.